# Why is this returning null before returning actual element

Tags: javascript, null

Why is this returning `null` before returning the actual element?

```
const subNav = document.querySelector('.subnav-block');
console.log(subNav);
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/rXBgNR?editors=1111), lines 30 and 31

Answer (score 1):

The null is logged even before the dom is rendered, hence couldn't find the element.